Network setup for a mobile robot base
I am working on a mobile robot base that is supposed to be controlled from a stationary control station. The robot itself has multiple processors onboard, which are on an internal Ethernet network. The control software is distributed accross these processors, and use ROS2 to communicate. The main controller onboard is running Ubuntu server 22.04, and only it connects to the main router, which is on the control station, using several WiFi access points throughout the building. Network configuration is managed by netplan using NetworkManager as the backend.
What I'd like to do is have the main controller somehow bridge the two networks without NAT. There is another server on the main network that I can use for this as well.
It ideally should be able to:

Route all traffic including broadcast packets, basically acting identically to a direct Ethernet link between the two, or at least allow ROS2 DDS packets to go through
Use the main router for DHCP
Have minimal latency, though throughput is less important

Basically what I'm looking for is a WiFi client bridges, but the ones I have are bound to a single AP MAC and don't roam at all.
I first tried using netplan to set up a bridge between the WiFi interface and Ethernet, but adding the WiFi interface to a bridge causes it to never become up, somehow. I then set up dnsmasq and iptables to have the main controller act as a seperate DHCP server and NAT router, but this blocks most traffic going through, and does not allow ROS2 nodes to communicate with the main network.
What I have in mind:

Tailscale, as it also allows subnets to be shared over it, but I haven't tested if it lets broadcast packets through, and I think a more lightweight solution should be possible on a local network, as I don't need the traffic to go over the internet.
DHCP relay on the main controller, however this doesn't solve the routing issues. I also haven't been able to get it to work at all, I'm guessing because of the WiFi connection in between.
1 to 1 NAT, but I couldn't find any up-to-date info on how to set one up on Ubuntu.

I've heard IPv6 eliminates the need for NAT, combined with a DHCP relay it may be possible to accomplish this, but I couldn't find anything on how to set up IPv6 routing either. Maybe my Google-fu is lacking.
It's also possible that I'm overcomplicating things. Is what I'm trying to do possible at all?

Nice well formulated question, but (and I might be wrong) it doesn't seem particularly robotics related, but more of a general networking question.

I previously posted it in a more relevant space, but I got recommended to post it here instead.

Oh right. Ok, fair enough. Hopefully you will get an answer. Good luck. :-)

Welcome to Robotics, feoranis. As I mention in my comment on your question over at Ask Ubuntu, this really looks more like a network setup question than something for Robotics. You may even ask over at Network Engineering to see what mechanism they suggest to achieve your goals, and then you can ask over at Ask Ubuntu if you need help on the implementation. Whatever you choose to do, it sounds like the robot is driving your needs, but your problem is with the network configuration.

I tried that as well, but the question got quickly closed since they only handle enterprise networks, apparently. I'm sorry if this is off topic here as well, I just couldn't find anywhere else that this question would fit.

That is a shame about Network.SE, only being for enterprise. I didn't know that. It isn't that your question is off-topic here, per se. It is more that it is a pure networking issue (the fact that the computers accessing the network in this case are robots isn't really relevant). So, to get a good answer, you should ask on a site where there is a lot of networking knowledge - and maybe rephrase the question so that you don't mention the robots, just say that they are computers (if that makes sense). For networking issues, Ask Ubuntu would be ok, if you say that you are using ubuntu computers..

Or Super User could also be a good candidate, as they deal with a lot of home networking stuff. Again, just say that the robots are Linux machines (because whenever you mention they are robots, then people will advise you to ask here). Maybe Unix&Linux.SE, they also have some network stuff. If you leave your question here, then it is on topic, but I don't think that there are many networking experts on this site (I might be wrong, of course). It is best to ask on a site that is most likely to provide you with a good answer. I hope that explains it a bit more.Good luck where ever you post :-)

Another example of finding the best site was a question we had on 3DP.SE, about a robot that can 3D Print. It certainly didn't fit on Robotics.SE. However, it is more of a coding/compiling issue, so Stack Overflow would seem better. However, in fact, it could really just be a Github issue on the repository of the software being compiled.
